# Get Coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, maps

I have the following tif metada:

```
        Geotiff_Information:
           Version: 1
           Key_Revision: 1.0
           Tagged_Information:
              ModelTiepointTag (2,3):
                 0                0                0                
                 275599.883       8945300.09       0                
              ModelPixelScaleTag (1,3):
                 0.2              0.2              0                
              End_Of_Tags.
           Keyed_Information:
              GTModelTypeGeoKey (Short,1): User-Defined
              GTRasterTypeGeoKey (Short,1): RasterPixelIsArea
              GeographicTypeGeoKey (Short,1): GCS_WGS_84
              GeogAngularUnitsGeoKey (Short,1): Angular_Degree
              ProjLinearUnitsGeoKey (Short,1): Linear_Meter
              End_Of_Keys.
           End_Of_Geotiff.

        GCS: 4326/WGS 84
        Datum: 6326/World Geodetic System 1984
        Ellipsoid: 7030/WGS 84 (6378137.00,6356752.31)
        Prime Meridian: 8901/Greenwich (0.000000/  0d 0' 0.00"E)
        Projection Linear Units: 9001/metre (1.000000m)

        Corner Coordinates:
        Upper Left    (  275599.883, 8945300.088)
        Lower Left    (  275599.883, 8943699.888)
        Upper Right   (  277200.083, 8945300.088)
        Lower Right   (  277200.083, 8943699.888)
        Center        (  276399.983, 8944499.988)
```

I would like to know how to get / convert the coordinates in the google maps format (eg: `-9.6791741,-77.1082426,12`).

Comment: Do you have any idea what the lat-long coordinates should be, roughly? What part of the earth should it be on, and how big?

Comment: I think your data is bogus - there is no valid lon/lat coordinates in degrees (which is what the GCS: 4326 means) with those numbers.  Suggest asking whoever made it to try again.

Comment: I can open with QGis https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-z_bpyN9_qNTU9kUUpoMlZkU28 and it still show those coordinates(EPSG:4326):         Upper Left    (  275599.883, 8945300.088)
, what is happening ?